# Used Car Purchase

Tags: car

I am planning to buy a used car from a dealer. The bank requires copy of title for loan approval. But the dealer refuses to share it (as per their protocol) until the vehicle is purchased. Is there a way to get copy of the title from anywhere else. Pls suggest

Comment: People take out loans to buy used cars all the time. So either your bank or your car dealer is out of step. If neither of them budge, maybe you could use an escrow service?

Comment: This might be a "tote the note" lot that will only finance through their (usually predatory) financing connections. Tell them you can't buy the car without a copy of the title and see if they budge

Comment: The dealer likely doesn't own the car.

Comment: Why in the world are you getting a loan for a car?  Pay cash or don't buy.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the dealer doesn't want you to get a loan from the bank. He wants you to get a loan from a financing company that gives him a cut.

So it's really simple. You tell him "give me a copy of a title, or I walk". And if he refuses to give you the title, you walk. You are dealing with a dishonest person, so you really don't want to do business with them.

Answer (score 4):

How about you request they fax a copy to the bank directly? If they are concerned you will take over ownership of the car by having a photocopy of the title that should alleviate their concerns.

If they won't budge on that, walk. They really don't want to sell that car very badly or are up to something fishy.